# How to build dynamic queries with laravel

Tags: php, laravel

so I have a question. With laravel u can use the Eloquent library to create dynamic queries, but here's my problem. I have an external database which has stored procedures I need to call. I figured out that this code works.

```
$results = DB::connection('sqlsrv')->select($query);
```

But I need to know if there's a way to build the query dynamically cause not all the data in my form must be filled tho my stored procedure requires either some value or 'NULL' otherwise.

Here's what I have so far and it works, but it's not dynamic and I have to make a lot of junk make it so

```
 $query = 'exec PROCEDURE_HERE "'.$request->name.'","'.$request->flastname.'","'.$request->mlastname.'",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,"'.$request->datepicker.'",0,null';
```

And I have this function to handle the null values but the problem is since the query have " (those things) to build the query my final query looks like this

```
public function adaptRequest(Request $request){
        if (!isset($request->name)){
            $request->name = "null";
        }
        if (!isset($request->flastname)){
            $request->flastname = "null";
        }
        if (!isset($request->mlastname)){
            $request->mlastname = "null";
        }
        if ($request->datepicker == ""){
            $request->datepicker = "null";
        }
        return $request;
    }

exec PROCEDURE "null","null","null",null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,null,0,null,"null",0,null
```

What I need to know is if there's a way to work this thing around like java does with Prepared statements where in the variables I place a '?' and then fill the data separately, kinda like this and then fill the '?'

```
$query = 'exec PROCEDURE_HERE ??,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?'
```

Any help would be awesome thanks

Comment: You should be able to do e.g. `select(DB::raw("exec procedure ?, ?, ?", [$arg1, $arg2, $arg3]))` or similar.

Comment: Ok let me try that

Answer (score 1):

Use query in this form:

```
$query = User::select(...)->join(..);
if(condition){
    $query->where(...);
}
if(condition){
    $query->where(...);
}
$query->get(...);
```